# Is there a way to get the JMSMessageID using Spring Integration Message Object

Tags: spring-integration

We have a need to Pass the JMSMessageID  (generated by IBM Mq Queuemanger). 
My problem is the how do i populate the value in the MessageHeaders 
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders and pass it to my Activator.

Comment: are you reading or writing?

Comment: ah, then it's simple. have you tried? it should work fine by default.

Comment: No by default i just have Timestamp and UUID in the header no JMSMessageId. We are using message-driven-channel-adapter (To read) if it helps.

Comment: The messaging system gets to allocate those.  -- As you said i need to use what ever the messaging system allocated.

Comment: public Map<String, Object> toHeaders(javax.jms.Message jmsMessage)  -- this method should do it but for some reason i dont see them do all adapters implement this ?

Comment: Perhaps your spring context has a custom headermapper configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the jms_messageId is getting populated. I was using a JUNIT test which was not going through the Quemanager so those header values are not being set by my program, So i had the change the Junit to copy the Headers it worked.
Thanks a bunch.

Something like this in my junits

```
    Map<String, String> headersToCopy = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headersToCopy.put("JMSXUserID", "suren");
    headersToCopy.put("jms_messageId", "ID:1234567894444444444444");
    headersToCopy.put("JMS_IBM_MsgType", "8");
    headersToCopy.put("JMSXDeliveryCount", "1");
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The [`DefaultJmsHeaderMapper`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-jms/2.2.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/integration/jms/DefaultJmsHeaderMapper.java#DefaultJmsHeaderMapper.toHeaders%28javax.jms.Message%29) will add the inbound `JmsMessageId` as header `jms_messageId` to the spring integration message's MessageHeaders.